# Counting club memberships in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT: I have added the primary key, following the comment by @Strawberry

The aim is to return the number of current members, and also the number of past memberships, on any particular date/time.

For example, suppose we have

```
msid  id  start                 cancelled
1     1   2020-01-01 09:00:00   null
2     2   2020-01-01 09:00:00   2020-12-31 09:00:00
3     2   2021-01-01 09:00:00   null
4     3   2020-01-01 09:00:00   2020-06-30 09:00:00
5     3   2020-02-01 09:00:00   2020-06-30 09:00:00
6     3   2020-07-01 09:00:00   null
```

and we want to calculate the number of members at various times, which should return as follows

```
Datetime            Current  Past    <Notes - not to be returned by the query>
2020-01-01 12:00:00   3       0    -- all 3 IDs have joined earlier on this date
2020-02-01 12:00:00   3       0    -- new membership for existing member (ID 3) is not counted
2020-06-30 12:00:00   2       1    -- ID 3 has cancelled earlier on this day
2020-07-01 12:00:00   3       0    -- ID 3 has re-joined earlier on this day
2020-12-31 12:00:00   2       1    -- ID 2 has cancelled earlier on this day
2021-01-01 12:00:00   3       0    -- ID 2 has re-joined earlier on this day
```

An ID may either be current or past, but never both. That is, if a past member re-joins, as in the case of ID 2 and 3 above, they become current members, and are no longer past members.

Also, a member may have multiple current memberships, but they can only be counted as a current member once, as in the case of ID 3 above.

How can this be achieved in MySQL ?

[Here is a db<>fiddle with the above data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60a0e83f82d9143ba7158af80ca458f2)

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry there is "membership_id", which is unique in this table, but I didn't think it was relevant to the problem.

Comment: Well, I think it's relevant :-(

Comment: @Strawberry OK I have added the primary key. Thanks :)

Comment: How are the target date times generated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it could either be a list of dates taken from another table, to generate the output in the question, or it could be just a single date. I would be happy with either (or both!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT start `timestamp` FROM dt
          UNION 
          SELECT cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT id
          FROM dt )
SELECT cte1.`timestamp`, COUNT(DISTINCT dt.id) current, SUM(dt.id IS NULL) past
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
LEFT JOIN dt ON cte1.`timestamp` >= dt.start
            AND (cte1.`timestamp` < dt.cancelled OR dt.cancelled IS NULL)
            AND cte2.id = dt.id
GROUP BY cte1.`timestamp`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=942e4c97951ed0929e178134ef67ce69

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be excellent (+1)